# Javascript/HTML textarea count letters (no spaces) and words

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textarea

I'm a coding noob...I'm working on an assignment to create a textarea that will capture the user input then calculate the characters (excluding spaces) and calculate the word count.
It does everything but the final character/word count.
Can anybody please help me with what I'm missing.

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <td width="100%">
    <textarea rows="12" name="charcount" cols="60" wrap="virtual"></textarea>
  </td>
  <tr>
    <td width="100%">
      <div align="center">
        <p>
          <input type="button" value="Calculate Characters" onClick="countit(this)">
          <input type="text" name="displaycount" size="20">
        </p>
        <div align="center">
          <center>
            <font face="arial" size="-2">
          </center>
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <td width="100%">
    <div align="center">
      <p>
        <input type="button" value="Calculate Words" onClick="countit()">
        <input type="text" name="wordcount3" size="20">
      </p>
    <div align="center">
      <center></center>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Hi Chris! You should accompany your post with some code showcasing what you're *trying* to do, and what you've tried so far. This will go a long way towards improving your chances of an answer. If you want to learn how to ask really good questions, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

To count the words you break the string on word boundaries.

As a shortcut I'll show spaces but truth is, you should pay more attention to what a *word boundary* really is:

```
w = s.split(" ");
```

The number of words is:

```
w.length
```

Again, this is a shortcut. To get the REAL number of words you should check each item in `w` that it is not empty.

The number of characters without spaces is just the length of the string minus the word count minus one:

```
s.length - (w.length - 1)
```

And again, that's a rough approach. What about inter-punctuation? There is a more accurate but complex approach for everything I have said here.

**EDIT:** this would be better HTML albeit it's not clear what layout etc. you want to get. As I have said in the comment, I shouldn't even answer you. Don't know why I'm doing this. Well, here it is:

```
<form>
  <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <textarea name="charcount" rows="12" cols="60" wrap="virtual"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="button" value="Calculate Characters" onClick="countit(this)" />
        <input type="text" name="displaycount" size="20" readonly="readonly" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="button" value="Calculate Words" onClick="countit()" />
        <input type="text" name="wordcount3" size="20" readonly="readonly" />
       </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I didn't have my code added into my post originally.  What would your recommendation be for the way I have it written thus far?

Comment: I have fixed the indent of you HTML. It should be easy to spot where you don't have closed your tags... There are several errors for several different reasons. I couldn't even start to explain, it's far too messy and the explanation to long and broad. You should ask a new question for this but you would get closed pretty soon, so I've edited it in my answer but I cannot even start to tell you why all these changes are for the better. Just study HTML 5 on a good website if you want to write correct HTML. It's really the easiest thing there is in computer science.